# css to style the width of a select element

Tags: css, select

I can not find a way to make a select element to have a specific width, no matter how big it is his content.

I have try something like:

```
<select style='width:10px;'>
```

But if the content is larger than that it will increase its size.

Comment: Your example isn't showing.

Comment: you need `width:10px;`

Comment: When I try it, the select box is the width I set. See http://jsfiddle.net/RrUFe/. However, the drop-down elements will be visible, otherwise the select is not useful. So I'm not sure what the problem is that you're describing.

Comment: i don't have a problem either. what browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry misswrite the code. Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use !important clause:

```
<select style='width:10px; !important'>
```

For reference: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/
(or any other source, there are plenties of them)

Comment: You can add also max-width:10px; !important, see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp